# Is the solution stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I've got the following system of equations:

$x' = -x -2y + x^2y^2$ and $y'=x-\frac{1}{2} y - \frac{1}{2} x^3y$

I have to check whether zero solution (solution for x=y=0) is stable. Is it Lyapunov stable? Is it asymptotically stable?

Please, may somebody show me the full solution? This is the subject I have to prepare without my teacher for the exam and I would really like to have it absolutely right, from the beginning till the end.

Comment: Can you add what you've done?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x = -x - 2y + \phi (x,y) \\ 
\dot y =  x - \frac{y}{2}  + \psi (x,y) \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
The functions $\psi (x,y)$ and $\phi (x,y)$ can be ignored ($x \to 0$,  $y \to 0$) at infinitesimal neighborhood of zero. So ..
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        -1-\lambda & -2 \\
        1 & -0.5-\lambda \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$
$$\lambda^2 + \frac{3}{2} \lambda + \frac{5}{2} = 0 $$
$$\lambda_1 = \frac{-3}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{31}i}{4} = 0;     \lambda_2 = \frac{-3}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{31}i}{4} = 0 $$
If the all of $\lambda $'s real parts ($Re \lambda$) values are below zero, then the zero-solution $y \equiv 0$ is asymptotically stable.

In this case, it is stable.

---

For the Lyapunov stability investigation the Lyapunov function must be created. It's look is $V = ax^2 + by^2, a>0, b>0$ - are any parameters one likes.
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dV}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} = 2ax(-x-2y+x^2y^2)+2by(x-\frac{y}{2}-\frac{1}{2}x^3y)=-(2ax^2+by^2)+(2xy-x^3y^2)(b-2a).$$
Then $b=2a$, it easy to see, that$\frac{dV}{dt}=-2a(x^2 + y^2) \le 0 $.
$$V = ax^2 + 2ay^2, a>0$$ - positive definite function and it's derivative is a negative definite one - so it was a formulation of the Lyapunov theorem about stability. I hope this stability is a Lyapunov stability.